# How to sum the total rows after apply sorting using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I fetch the records from the database to a html table. At the footer of table I shows the total sum of all the rows. Here is the code I write to sum all the rows

```
var sums = []
$("#tblexpensereport tbody tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find("td").each(function(i, x) {
        if ($(x).html().length) {
            var tdValue = parseInt($(x).html());
            tdValue = (tdValue + parseInt(sums[i] == undefined ? 0 : sums[i]))
            sums[i] = tdValue
        }
    })
})
var counter = 1;
$.each(sums, function(i, x) {
    if (isNaN(x)) {
        $("tfoot tr").append("<td></td>")
    } else {
        counter++;
        console.log('Counter:', counter + ' ' + x);
        if (counter == '2') {
            $("tfoot tr").append("<td style='font-weight:bold;display:none;'></td>");
        } else {
            $("tfoot tr").append("<td style='font-weight:bold;'>" + x + "</td>");
        }
    }
})
```

Now after all these I add the dropdown for filter this table. After filter the record I am not able to get the total sum of filter records. So anybody can please let me know how to do sum of total rows after filter the table using jquery

Thanks

Comment: Why dont you just get the lenght with php?

Comment: Use the https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/ to only loop over the currently visible rows to begin with when summing up the values.

Comment: can you please add filter click/change event

Comment: @04FS's comment might help in general. What plugin are you using for applying filtering to the table? There might also be a plugin specific solution for this.